# CXF wsdl2java - generate list without wrapper (static inner class)

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, cxf, wsdl2java

I'm trying to make a ws and I have small problem with classes generated by cxf.

Whenever I try to make a list, it is generated as a field of static inner class(wrapper).

for example

```
<xs:complexType name="customer">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="customerId" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element name="orders">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="order" type="tns:order" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="order">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long" />
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

would generate

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "customer", propOrder = {
"customerId",
"orders"
})
public class Customer {

    protected int customerId;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Customer.Orders orders;
...
    public static class Orders {

        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected List<Order> order;
...
```

and what I would like to get is

```
public class Customer {

    protected int customerId;
    protected List<Order> orders;
...
```

the xml for this example type should look like:

```
<customer>
    ...
    <orders>
        <order>
            <id></id>
            <name></name>
        </order>
        <order>
            <id></id>
            <name></name>
        </order>
        ...
    </orders>
</customer>
```

from what I understand, @XmlRootElement could be used when doing java2wsdl, but is there some way to generate this type of class from wsdl?

Currently calling customer.getOrders().getOrder() would return a list of orders which is a little counterintuitive

Comment: Hi I face the same question. Did you find an answer? Is there a way to do this without jaxb-xew-plugin? I am facing a constraint where I can't use 3rd party plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with the same issue (CXF wsdl2java) and solved it using the [jaxb-xew-plugin](https://github.com/dmak/jaxb-xew-plugin).